# Postgresql support for national character data types

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

Looking for a reference that discusses PostgreSQL's support for the NATIONAL CHARACTER set of data types.  e.g. this query runs without error:

```
select cast('foo' as national character varying(10))
```

yet the docs don't seem to discuss that type [Postgres character data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html)

Does Postgres implement these differently from the CHARACTER data types?  That is, how does the NATIONAL keyword affect how data is stored or represented?

Can someone share a link or two to any references I can't seem to find? (other than some mailing list correspondence from a while back)

Comment: There is no such concept as "national characters" in PostgreSQL. In few words: there are database-wide settings (when you create the new database): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html - look at the `encoding`, `lc_collate` and `lc_ctype` options; and "collation": https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html Honestly I not experimented with this a lot just because using `UTF8` encoding is enough for all projects that I working on.

Comment: Yeah I get that.  Just curious that the compiler accepts the NATIONAL keyword.  I suppose that's just for compatibility and does nothing special under the hood.

Comment: By the way, this kind of Question might do better in the sister site: https://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you request a `national character varying` in PostgresSQL, you'll get a regular `character varying`.

PostgreSQL uses the same encoding for normal and national characters.

“National character” is a leftover from the bad old days when people still used single-byte encodings like `LATIN-1` and needed a different encoding for characters that didn't fit.

PostgreSQL has always supported UNICODE encodings, so this is not an issue. Just make sure that you don't specify an encoding other than the default `UTF8`.

Answer (score 1):

`NATIONAL CHARACTER` has **no real meaning** in the SQL:92 standard (section 4.2.1), saying only that it means “a particular implementation-defined character repertoire”. If you are surprised, don’t be. There are many screwy aspects to the SQL standard.

As for text handling in Postgres, you would likely be interested in learning about:

- [character encoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/multibyte.html)

  - [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)
  - [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)
- [collations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html)

  - support for [ICU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Components_for_Unicode) in Postgres 10 and later.

See:

- [*More robust collations with ICU support in PostgreSQL 10*](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/icu-support-postgresql-10/) by Peter Eisentraut, post, 2017-05.
- [*Collations: Introduction, Features, Problems*](https://youtu.be/e0lP_K1rd98) by Peter Eisentraut, video, 2019-07-12.
- [*Unicode collation algorithm ( UCA )*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_collation_algorithm)
- [*ICU User Guide – Locale*](http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale)
- [List of locales with 209 languages, 501 regions & variants, as defined in ICU](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp)